# A doubt regarding charge distribution in conductors

Tags: electrostatics, conductors

Why only the excess charge reside on the surface of conductors and not the free electrons inside it?

Comment: Welcome to Physics.SE! I suggest the following: 1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by answering questions in your area of expertise. 2) Take the [tour](http://physics.stackexchange.com/tour)! 3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://i.stack.imgur.com/eNrdG.png), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. 4) If you get a satisfactory answer, remember to accept it by clicking on the green checkmark.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because the negative charges are all pushing away from each other, and the furthest possible space they could be is at the surface (unless there are so many that they're forced to pop off)

Comment: Welcome to Physics.SE! I suggest the following: 1) Take the [tour](http://physics.stackexchange.com/tour)! 2) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://i.stack.imgur.com/eNrdG.png), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. 3) If you have a good question, ask it! Just search for duplicates and follow the [help center rules](http://physics.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).